# Не срабатывает textAlign: TextAlign.center

Tags: flutter

Не срабатывает выравнивание текста по центру, в чем может быть ошибка?

```
appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'Flutter',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 25,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
              color: Colors.limeAccent,
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
AppBar(
  centerTitle: true, // Это то что вам нужно
  title: Text(
    'Flutter',
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 25,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
      color: Colors.limeAccent,
    ),
  ),
)
```